# Custom pagination in Django is not working properly

Tags: django, pagination

I created a pagination in django using a dropdown which lists the pages for the user to select from. When any value is selected a javascript function is called which calls the django backend to fetch the data.

The response object from django includes the page number which was selected so that the same page can be kept selected in HTML (since the page reloads to render the template).

```
<div>
    Pages :
<select name="pagination" id="pagination_id" onchange="pageChange()">
    {% for i in pages %}
    <option value={{i}} {% if page_selected == i %} selected="selected" {% endif %}> {{i}} </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</div>
```

However, the dropdown selection is always the first item even though the data in HTML table changes. The value in `page_selected` is appropriate but the dropdown does not select on the correct page. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What did you pass as context? What is `pages` and `page_selected`?

Comment: Context object is something like { 'pages':pages, 'page_selected':page_selected, ... } 
 where pages is a list of integers [1,2,3 ... n] and page_selected is the value from dropdown which the user selected (one of the n values in pages). @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: but then likely `page_selected` is a *string*, a string that contains a sequence of digits, but `5` is not the same as `'5'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the parameter directly from `request.GET`, then the `page_selected` is a *string*.

You should cast it to an integer, with `int(…)`:

```
context = {
    'pages': pages,
    'page_selected': int(page_selected),
    # …
}
```